# Stack Overflow Error caused by Method Call

Tags: c#, stack-overflow

I am trying to fix this error so that I can start my program with 4 instances in my list "school" that I declare internally. Then I want to allow the user to manipulate the list as they wish. Everything was working until I added the method "Myfour". How Can I call this so that the stack overflow error doesn't present? I am new to programming and C# and need this completed today.

The Main:

```
using System;

namespace Lab4
{
    class MainClass
    {
        public static void Main (string[] args)
        {

            Console.WriteLine ("Welcome to the Course Monitoring System v1.0");
            Course myCourse = new Course();
            myCourse.Myfour ();
            myCourse.Print ();
            Course.Menu();
            myCourse.Print ();
            myCourse.Choice();
        }
    }
}
```

The Course Class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace Lab4
{
    public class Course
    {
        private string courseNumber;
        private string courseName;
        private int courseHours;
        public List<Course> school = new List<Course> ();
        private int howmany=0;
        private int totalcourse=0;

        //This section is for returning and adjusting values of private data through the main program.
        public string cn{
            get {return courseNumber; }
            set {if (value != null)
                cn = value;
            }
        }
        public string name{
            get{ return courseName; }
            set{if (value!="")
                name=courseName;
            }
        }
        public int hours{
            get {return courseHours; }
            set {if (value != 0)
                hours = value;
            }
        }

        public Course()
        {
        }
        public Course (string name, string cn, int hours)
        {
            courseNumber = cn;
            courseName = name;
            courseHours = hours;
        }

        //This portion of code overrides the string and allows it to output the information held within the constructor.
        public override string ToString ()
        {
            return courseNumber+" " + courseName + " " +" It is a " + courseHours + " hour course.";
        }
        //The menu application for my program
        public static void Menu()
        {
            Console.WriteLine ("Please choose from one of the following options: ");
            Console.WriteLine ("......................................................................");
            Console.WriteLine ("1.)Start a new Course List.");
            Console.WriteLine ("2.)Delete Course from Current List.");
            Console.WriteLine ("3.)Print Current Course List.");
            Console.WriteLine ("4.)Add Course to Current List.");
            Console.WriteLine ("5.)Shutdown Program");
        }
        //This is the controller for the menu. It allows for functionality to control the tasks requested by the user.
        public void Choice()
        {
            int selection=int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            while (selection >5 || selection < 1) {
                Console.WriteLine ("Choice invalid. Please choose between 1 and 5.");
                selection = int.Parse (Console.ReadLine ());
            }
            if (selection == 4) {
                Add ();
                Menu ();
                Choice ();
                Console.WriteLine ();
            }
            if (selection == 2) {
                Delete ();
                Menu ();
                Choice ();
                Console.WriteLine ();
            }
            if (selection == 3) {
                Print ();
                Menu ();
                Choice ();
                Console.WriteLine ();
            }
            if (selection == 1) {
                New ();
                Menu ();
                Choice ();
                Console.WriteLine ();
            }
            if (selection == 5) {
                Console.WriteLine ();
                Console.WriteLine ("Thank you for using this program for your scheduling needs.");
            }
        }
        //This method when called will print a numbered list of courses refrenced by the created List
        public void Print()
        {
            Console.WriteLine ();
            Console.WriteLine ("Course Name.........Course Number.........Course Description........Course Hours");
            Console.WriteLine ("********************************************************************************");
            for (int i = 0; i < totalcourse; i++) {
                int place = i + 1;
                Console.WriteLine (place+".)"+school [i]);
            }
            Console.WriteLine ();
        }
        //This method will add an item to the end of the current list.
        public void Add()
        {
            Console.WriteLine ();
            Console.Write ("How many courses would you like to add at the end of your index?");
            int numberAdded = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine ());
            for (int i = 0; i < numberAdded; i++) {
                Console.WriteLine ("Please use the following templet for your entries...");
                Console.WriteLine ("Course Prefix, Course Name, Course Number, Course Hours, Course Description ");
                school.Add (new Course (courseName = Console.ReadLine (), courseNumber = Console.ReadLine (), courseHours = int.Parse (Console.ReadLine ())));
            }
            totalcourse = totalcourse + numberAdded;
            Console.WriteLine ();
        }
        //This method will delete an Item from the list based on the position 0-x based on x-1, the output that is seen by the user. After each iteration it will
        //also create a list so that further deletions can be managed approiatly.
        public void Delete()
        {
            if (totalcourse < 1) {
                Console.WriteLine ();
                Console.WriteLine ("There is nothing to delete!");
                Console.WriteLine ();
            }else{
                Console.WriteLine ();
                Console.Write ("How many entries do you wish to remove?");
                int removed = int.Parse (Console.ReadLine ());
                for (int i = 0; i < removed; i++) {
                    Console.WriteLine ("Please type the index line number of the item you wish to remove.");
                    int delete = int.Parse (Console.ReadLine ());
                    school.RemoveAt (delete - 1);
                    totalcourse = totalcourse - 1;
                    Print ();
                }
            }
            Console.WriteLine ();
        }
        //This method is called to create a new list of Courses to be created by the user.
        public void New()
        {
            Console.WriteLine ();
            if (howmany > 0) {
                Clear ();
            } else {
                Console.Write ("How many courses do you want to create? ");
                howmany = int.Parse (Console.ReadLine ());
                Console.WriteLine ();
                for (int i = 0; i < howmany; i++) {
                    Console.WriteLine ();
                    Console.WriteLine ("Please use the following templet for your entries...");
                    Console.WriteLine ("Course Prefix, Course Name, Course Number, Course Hours, Course Description ");
                    school.Add (new Course (courseName = Console.ReadLine (), courseNumber = Console.ReadLine (), courseHours = int.Parse (Console.ReadLine ())));
                }
                totalcourse = totalcourse + howmany;
                Console.WriteLine ();
            }
        }
        //If there is already a list in place this method will be called and you will be asked if you wish to delete and start new.
        public void Clear()
        {
            Console.WriteLine ();
            Console.Write ("You want to discard old work and start a new list? Enter True or False...:");
            bool clean=bool.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            if (clean == true) {
                school.Clear ();
                totalcourse = 0;
                howmany = 0;
                New ();
            } else
                Console.WriteLine ("No changes will be made. Exiting to Main Menu...");
            Console.WriteLine ();
        }
//This is the method to call the 4 predefined Courses
//----->This is the part of my code that is causing the stack overflow error that I cant figure out...
        public void Myfour ()
        {
            Console.WriteLine ("These are four pre loaded courses.");
            Course c1=new Course(name="Programming",cn="1101",hours=3);
            Course c2=new Course(name="Algebra",cn="1101",hours=4);
            Course c3=new Course(name="Chemistry 1",cn="1101",hours=4);
            Course c4=new Course(name="Chemistry 1 Lab",cn="1101",hours=3);
            school.Add (c1);
            school.Add (c2);
            school.Add (c3);
            school.Add (c4);

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can a Course have child Courses?  Probably not, but that's what your code is setup as.  That `school` variable shouldn't be inside the Course class.  The Menu doesn't look like it belongs inside that class either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The stack overflow is caused by assigning the property recursively. You shouldn't write like this:

```
public string cn{
    get {return courseNumber; }
    set {if (value != null)
        cn = value;
    }
}
```

See that cn is assigned again? You should change that line using the private variable like this:

```
public string cn{
    get {return courseNumber; }
    set {if (value != null)
        courseNumber = value;
    }
}
```

Do the same to the other properties. Also note the bug in Course Name. You should use value instead courseName. This is what it should be.

```
public string cn{
    get {return courseNumber; }
    set {if (value != null)
        courseNumber = value;
    }
}
public string name{
    get { return courseName; }
    set
    {
        if (value != "")
            courseName = value;
    }
}
public int hours{
    get {return courseHours; }
    set {if (value != 0)
        courseHours = value;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You have properties that set itself:

```
public string cn
{
    get { return courseNumber; }
    set
    {
        if (value != null)
            cn = value;
    }
}
```

This will infinitely loop. You should have some private fields to assign:

```
private string _cn;
public string cn
{
    get { return _cn; }
    set
    {
        if (value != null)
            _cn = value;
    }
}
```